# How to define matrix power

Tags: matrices, exponentiation

I am currently writing a scriptum struggling with the definition of matrix power. Precisely, let $ \mathbb A \in \mathbb C^{n, n} $ and $ p \in \mathbb R $. I Currently have:

- If $ p \in \mathbb N $ then $ \mathbb A^p = \prod_{i = 1}^p \mathbb A $
- If A is hermitian and positively define and $ \mathbb A = \mathbb U^* \mathbb{DU} $ is the Schur decomposition, then $ \mathbb D $ is diagonal. We define $ \mathbb D^p $ as a diagonal matrix with $ ( \mathbb D^p )_{ii} = ( \mathbb D_{ii} )^p $. We define $ \mathbb A^p = \mathbb U^* \mathbb D^p \mathbb U $
- If $ \mathbb A = \mathbb T^{-1} \mathbb{J T} $ is the Jordan decomposition, we define $ \mathbb A^p = \mathbb T^{-1} \mathbb J^p \mathbb T $

None of these is correct however, for the first and second one have their limitations to $ p $ and $ \mathbb A $ respectively and the third one defines matrix powers using matrix powers. So, how to define matrix power so that it works with any matrix and any exponent?

I know how powers od real numbers are defined (as multiplication, later as roots for rational exponents, and finally as limits for powers of $ e $ and from that fr powers of other numbers... And then you have to prove that all of these are consistent) and I hope it won't be that complicated for matrices.

I can also prove that all of these definitions are equal (when they work).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_function#Jordan_decomposition

Comment: The notion of $A^p$ for $p$ not an integer is not commonly studied.  I suppose if $A$ is diagonalizable, i.e. $A=QDQ^{-1}$, then you could define $A^p=QD^pQ^{-1}$, where $D^p$ is defined by taking the diagonal entries of $D$ to the power $p$.  For non-diagonalizable $A$ there doesn't seem to be a natural definition.

Comment: See also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_2_by_2_matrix), where one may define an exponent of 1/2, with some difficulty, in the $2\times 2$ case.

Comment: I know the formula for integer powers of Jordan matrix, but it is only applicable to integer exponents as well.....
Also, there is one (quite) commonly used example of non-integer power - the definition of energetic norm:  $ \lVert \mathbb B \rVert_A = \lVert \mathbb A^{1/2} \mathbb B \mathbb A^{-1/2} \rVert_2 $